# S4 cant unlock my phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, password

I have a galaxy s4. I had the screen locked with a pattern. My 1year old daughter got a hoed of my phone and after the 5 incorrect patterns it asked for the pin. I entered the pin incorrectly  5 times so it asked me to wait 30 secs before trying again. Now I have the bar that says type pin code but when I tap the bar to type it in the keyboard does not pop up as usual so how do get the keyboard to pop up to enter the pin. I have tried restarting the phone, by pressing restart and shutting down and powering back up the phone  and  taking out the battery.

Answer (score -1):

What specific code is it asking for? Cell phone companies can give u your plu code to enter and unlock to restore phone. Or performing a master reset manually..keyboard won't pop up right?